# I'm moving users from one failing RDS to another and would like to take their numerous email accounts with them

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rds

I'm moving users from one failing RDS to another and would like to take their numerous email accounts with them without having to set them all up again. The exchange one moves no issue but we have external mail addresses which are not on our exchange server and it's a real pain having to reconfigure them all again.
Is there an easy way to do this...

Thanks in advance..

Jerry

Comment: Could you explain more about these "external mail addresses"?

Comment: we have numerous websites on which new clients complete online questionaires etc. We use e-mails hosted on one&one now known as IONOS.  we set them up in Outlook along side our default company exchange e-mail but they are not on our exchange.  They ae configured as iMap and each user can have up to 10 different emails.

Answer (score 0):

Moving Outlook Profile to New Computer should be a possible workaround. However, if the migration is not fully complete, it can easily lead to Outlook errors. Manually re-configure should be the the safest way. Check if the suggestions mentioned in this article could help. https://www.remosoftware.com/info/move-outlook-profile-to-new-computer

Comment: Right now this is very close to (and from some perspectives, truly) a link-only answer. Could you add some of the suggested fixes from that link in your answer to make that less of an issue?